# oracle update a part of a string ( semicolon seperated )

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update a part of a string between 2 semicolons. I played around with replace, but not successfully.

Before update, input column is:

> 52515117353;29/0/2005;15:10:12;Abgleichstation;whatever:

Expected Output

> 52515117353;29/12/2015;15:10:12;Abgleichstation;whatever:

The part after the first semicolon is date field and it was imported incorrectly from a csv file.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the rows in the database]

I need to update the string value #1 from screenshot with the value of #.

Comment: I am assuming these strings are in an oracle table column. You could try to use REGEXP_REPLACE function to replace the value after the first semicolon.

Comment: If the date value is the same for all rows in  the table, then simply use the replace function like so:
select 
replace(
  '52515117353;29/0/2005;15:10:12;Abgleichstation;whatever:',
  ';29/0/2005;15:10:12;',
  ';29/12/2015;15:10:12;')
  
from dual;

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to concatenate substrings.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, edi_line, a_datecre) as
  2    (select 1, '52511;1/0/2155;15:40:52;Abgle; ;1;15;2.18;2.20', '26/10/2022 15:19:57' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '52509;1/0/2155;15:34:23;Abgle; ;1;15;2.15;2.17', '26/10/2022 15:19:56' from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select id,
  6    substr(edi_line, 1, instr(edi_line, ';', 1, 1)) ||  -- up to 1st semicolon
  7    substr(a_datecre, 1, 10)                        ||  -- new date value
  8    substr(edi_line, instr(edi_line, ';', 1, 2)) result -- from 2nd semicolon to the end of the EDI_LINE
  9  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 52511;26/10/2022;15:40:52;Abgle; ;1;15;2.18;2.20
         2 52509;26/10/2022;15:34:23;Abgle; ;1;15;2.15;2.17

SQL>
```

I *presumed* that `a_datecre` column's datatype is `VARCHAR2`. If it is `DATE`, line #7 would be modified to

```
  7    to_char(a_datecre, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

---

If **all** invalid values are the same, i.e. `1/0/2155`, `replace` them:

```
  5  select id,
  6    replace(edi_line, '1/0/2155', substr(a_datecre, 1, 10)) result
  7  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 52511;26/10/2022;15:40:52;Abgle; ;1;15;2.18;2.20
         2 52509;26/10/2022;15:34:23;Abgle; ;1;15;2.15;2.17

SQL>
```

This might, though, cause problems if there are `1/0/2155` values elsewhere in that string, and you want to leave them as they are. In that case, previous option would be a better one.

Also, such a `replace` won't work if `1/0/2155` actually differs between rows (so it is e.g. `2/5/2134` and similar).